# Azure DevOps - How to easily switch branches to use for multiple environments

Tags: azure-devops

I have four environments that I deploy to.

I also have four different code branches that we use to deploy code from.

We constantly switch the branches we use to deploy on these environments.

One time I want to build and deploy a daily branch on my test environment.

Later I want to build and deploy a enhancements branch on the same test environment.

Next I want to build and deploy the daily branch on my test2 environment.

I think you get the picture

We are currently using a manual process to pull from the branch we want deployed, then zip it up and push it to AWS code deploy.

Using Azure DevOps pipeline and release what is the easiest method to allow me to switch to use different branchs on different environments.

I currently have a successful setup in Azure DevOps that performs a gradle build, creates the artifact and then lets me push it over to AWS CodeDeploy on one of my environments. I just can't seem to figure out a way to eastily swtich the branch without creating tons of Azure pipelines and releases.

Thanks all!

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio as your main IDE?

Comment: Just going through Azure DevOps

Comment: Are you and would you be open to using Visual Studio? If so, it pairs very well with Azure DevOps, and it is very easy to switch branches, commit and push code, and even merge branches.

Comment: I am on the dev ops side and the engineers are doing the committing on there own end. On my end I want the ability to easily choose a branch and have it deployed on any environment that I choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you manually trigger a build pipeline by clicking `Queue` or `Run Pipeline`, A new windows shown as below will be prompted which allows you to switch the branches.

[image]

If you want to automatically deploy different branch to different environment. You can push the build artifacts over to AWS CodeDeploy in a release pipeline and set the branch filters. Please refer to below steps:

1, set branch filter in the build pipeline as shown in below screenshot [image]which will build the selected branched. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) for more information about triggers.

2, create a [release pipline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops) to push build artifacts over to AWS CodeDeploy.

And Set the **Artifact filters** which will only allow the artifacts built from the specified branch to be deployed to this tage.

[image]

Comment: I set the triggers to use several branches but it only runs/triggers the pipeline if I make a change to the master branch. I assume I do not need to make pipelines in every branch? I tried both setting the yaml to

   trigger:  
- '*'   

and I tried setting some of the branches up in the "Triggers" section in the "Override the YAML continuous integration trigger" section in the pipeline edit area. It only runs when i make a change in the master branch.

Comment: just to make sure: is your yaml build file present in every branch of the git repository? I think it might not be enough if it is present only in master branch

Comment: Yes, If you are using yaml pipeline. It must be present in every branch

Comment: Hi @Levi Lu-MSFT, how do you do the second step: create an AzureDevops release pipeline to push build artifacts over to AWS CodeDeploy., I have been trying and not find any information about that. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queue time variable to specify the branch name you would like to use on your build pipeline. You would need to:

1. Edit your build pipeline and create the variable on the "variables" tab. Make sure to mark the "Settable at queue time" check
   [variable creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtHzg.png)
2. Update the source of your build pipeline, to specify the new variable under the "Default branch" option. It would look something like this:
   [pipeline source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiJ4J.png)

RUN your pipeline. Before finally clicking on RUN, you will be able to specify the desire branch:
[set variable value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylWbN.png)

Hope this works